# Navigation Breaks in small resolutions

Tags: html, css

I have a website

http://www.captureyourgemstone.com/

which works fine on most of the devices except in small resolutions and mobile devices, it breaks the navigation. I use bootstrap columns for this header. Is there any work around I can use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If only the menu worries you, you can add these at the end of http://www.captureyourgemstone.com/arris_style.css:

```
div#navbar li { display: inline-block; }
div#navbar li a { float: none; padding: 0 14px; }
#navbar#navbar ul { white-space: normal; }
div#navbar { max-width: 100%; text-align: center; float: none; }
.header { height: 160px; }
```